# Scala Cats spy a method with mockito-scala-cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats, mockito-scala

I am trying to mock a method with mockito-scala-cats

For example

this is my class

```
class MyService {

  def getProperty(property: String): Either[Future, String, ExternalUser] = ???

}
```

and the test class

```
class MyServiceSpec extends FunSpec with MockitoSugar with MockitoCats {

  describe("MyServiceApiImpl") {
    it("get property") {
      val serviceApi = mock[MyService]
      whenF(serviceApi.getProperty("name")) thenReturn UserExternal()
    }
  }

}
```

I get

> could not find implicit value for parameter a: cats.Applicative[[B]cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,String,B]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your imports. The following code compiles for me

```
import org.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.cats.MockitoCats
import org.scalatest.FunSpec

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // check this import

import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.instances.future._ // and this import

class MyService {

  def getProperty(property: String): EitherT[Future, String, ExternalUser] = ???

}

class MyServiceSpec extends FunSpec with MockitoSugar with MockitoCats {

  describe("MyServiceApiImpl") {
    it("get property") {
      val serviceApi = mock[MyService]
      whenF(serviceApi.getProperty("name")) thenReturn ExternalUser()
    }
  }

}

case class ExternalUser()
```